# How to schedule a Teradata query in crontab?

Tags: cron, scheduled-tasks, teradata

My work requires me to refresh certain Teradata tables everyday. I came across crontab and been trying to schedule a small Teradata query. Following are the codes:

Teradata:

```
DROP TABLE S_BNKFRD.PV_TEMP;
CREATE TABLE S_BNKFRD.PV_TEMP AS
(
SELECT
Current_Time AS Curr_Time
)WITH DATA;
```

Crontab:

```
* * * * * cd && . ./.profile;BTEQ -p /DATA/home/pverma3/CronTab_Test_Piyush.sql
```

The Teradata query sits in the `CronTab_Test_Piyush.sql` file in the given location which I need to run every min (this was just a baby step towards learning on how to automate teradata queries before I set it up for my main queries).

I googled but could not find the crontab syntax exactly. Rather I found people talking about BTEQ, so gave it a try. (My colleague is running a SAS file like that using BGsas in place of BTEQ, but we are getting rid of SAS soon, so I wanted to do it using Teradata)

Kindly help. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer to create a shell script and, in that shell script, write my bteq as a heredoc:

```
#!/bin/bash

bteqSYSTEM="your teradata domain name or ip"
bteqUSER="your teradata username"
bteqPWD="your teradata password"

bteq <<- BTEQSCRIPT 1> /DATA/home/pverma3/bteq_output.log
        .LOGON ${bteqSYSTEM}/${bteqUSER},${bteqPWD}
        DROP TABLE S_BNKFRD.PV_TEMP;
        CREATE TABLE S_BNKFRD.PV_TEMP AS
        (
        SELECT
        Current_Time AS Curr_Time
        )WITH DATA;
        .LOGOFF
        .QUIT
BTEQSCRIPT
```

This compartmentalizes all of the necessary bits into a single file that is easily called from cron:

```
#call my script every day at 1am
0 1 * * * /bin/bash /path/to/this/script.sh
```

If you wanted to keep your existing SQL file and refer to it from your bteq script you could do:

```
#!/bin/bash

bteqSYSTEM="your teradata domain name or ip"
bteqUSER="your teradata username"
bteqPWD="your teradata password"

bteq <<- BTEQSCRIPT 1> /DATA/home/pverma3/bteq_output.log
        .LOGON ${bteqSYSTEM}/${bteqUSER},${bteqPWD}
        .RUN FILE=/DATA/home/pverma3/CronTab_Test_Piyush.sql;
        .LOGOFF
        .QUIT
BTEQSCRIPT
```

You may also consider putting that sql into a stored procedure and then just calling the procedure from your bteq. This way you keep all of the sql off the command line where it's a bit more difficult to edit it.